# Запись сообщений в journald

Tags: c++, логирование

В моей задачи, я реализую простую систему логирования. На данный момент, я могу записывать сообщения в :

- **File**
- **Stdout**
- **TCP socket**
- **UDP socket**
- **Syslog**

Но помимо этих вариантов, я должен записывать сообщения и в `journald`, в операционной системе Linux. Вопрос заключается в том, как мне это реализовать. В большинстве случаев, рекомендуется использовать

```cpp
#include <systemd/sd-journal.h>
```

Но при попытки подключения к этой библиотеке, выдается ошибка - файл не найден. Также, мне интересно, разве при записи сообщений в `syslog`, они не должны записываться и в `journald` ?

Я спрашиваю об этом потому, что при записи сообщений в `syslog` с помощью этой функции:

```cpp
syslog(priority, "%s", message.c_str());
```

записанные сообщения также отображаются и в `journalctl`.

Пример:

```cpp
#include <sys/syslog.h>

int main()
{
    syslog(3, "%s", "Hello!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```bsh
#linux:/home/linux # journalctl -f

Mar 24 01:44:08 linux log[21274]: Hello!
```

Comment: Попробуйте `apt install libsystemd-dev` выполнить предварительно.

Comment: В моей операционной системе (openSuse 15.2) установлен такой вот пакет: `libsystemd0`, который и предназначен для работы с `journald`-ом. Но, несмотря на установленный пакет, я все еще не могу использовать вышеуказанную библиотеку

Comment: Ваш пакет не содержит файлов для разработчика (dev).

Comment: к сожалению, dev-библиотеки не нахожу

Comment: Так я же написал в первом комментарии. См. например, [тут](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libsystemd-dev) описание: *"The libsystemd0 library provides interfaces to various systemd components.

This package contains the development files. "*